# sharepoint2010: CQWP Sort by managed metadata column

Tags: content-query-web-part

It is possible to get sorting on Managed metadata column? I get grouping and filtering on the columns working but not sorting.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default this will not work. So you have to extend content query webpart and use in `CreateChildControls` you have to add following two lines:

```
this.ProcessDataDelegate = new ProcessData(ProcessItems);
base.CreateChildControls();
```

next is to implement `ProcessItems`

```
protected DataTable ProcessItems(DataTable dt)
{
            //Code to add custom sorting logic goes here.
            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
            dv.Sort = "BusinessUnit ASC, Title ASC";
            return CreateTable(dv);
        }
```

`CreateTable(dv)` is a function that convert `DataView` to `DataTable`.

```
public static DataTable CreateTable(DataView obDataView)
        {
            if (null == obDataView)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException
                ("DataView", "Invalid DataView object specified");
            }

            DataTable obNewDt = obDataView.Table.Clone();
            int idx = 0;
            string[] strColNames = new string[obNewDt.Columns.Count];
            foreach (DataColumn col in obNewDt.Columns)
            {
                strColNames[idx++] = col.ColumnName;
            }

            IEnumerator viewEnumerator = obDataView.GetEnumerator();
            while (viewEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)viewEnumerator.Current;
                DataRow dr = obNewDt.NewRow();
                try
                {
                    foreach (string strName in strColNames)
                    {
                        dr[strName] = drv[strName];
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                obNewDt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            return obNewDt;
        }
```

Well that's it, you are done.